# Asp Net Core 2.1 - HttpContext.User retorna null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Estoy haciendo una api Rest usando asp net core 2.1 con Vue, en la cual necesito obtener los datos del usuario que inicio sesión. El problema es que cuando ingreso por el navegador, httpContext.User no obtiene los datos. Pero cuando lo pruebo con Postman si los obtiene. Ambos llevan el tocken en la petición.

Este es codigo de mi controlador

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            if (id != customers.Id)
                return BadRequest();

            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

                customers.UpdatedAt = dt;
                customers.UpdatedBy = user.Email;

                _context.Entry(customers).State = EntityState.Modified;

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

Codigo de Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection")));

                services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
                {
                    options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;

                })
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

                services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options => 
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = "yourdomain.com",
                        ValidAudience = "yourdomain.com",                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Llave_secreta"])),
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    });


                services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));

services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();

                services.AddCors();

                services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(ConfigureJson);


                services.AddMvc();


                services.AddSession();

                // services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

                services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors(builder => builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        );

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();

        }
```

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Le sugiero revisar bien el código que ha colocado en su pregunta *(porque a mi parecer, está incompleto)*. **[edit] la pregunta** con el código organizado y lo mínimo *(para ser entendido por la comunidad)*.

Comment: Quizás tu problema está en el orden, usas las llamadas a los servicios: `services.AddMvc()` 2 veces y luego de eso, la `services.AddSession();`